# Boost 1.64 Unit Test compilation failure

Tags: c++, boost-unit-test-framework

I'm starting to go through the tutorial for boost unit testing presented [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/test/doc/html/tutorials/new-year-resolution.html).

Using my initial code:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE my_first test
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
```

when I compile it I receive the following error:

```
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ',' before '<'    c:\boost_1_64_0\boost\test\utils\basic_cstring\compare.hpp
```

I've compiled boost myself and I'm using version 1.64 due to other dependency constraints. I'm also using Visual Studio 2017 Community.

How do I solve this problem please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I must have had a corrupt Boost install as after I rebuilt it worked successfully! I don't understand how boost may have become corrupted though as it was working fine.

Hmmmm...technology!